# is it possible to maintain the view state for client side render control?

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, viewstate

My custom control is to render the canvas element in the client side. i need to maintain the viewstate for my control?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    [JsonIgnore]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public CircularGaugeProperties Model
    {
        get
        {
    CircularGaugeProperties modelData = (CircularGaugeProperties)this.ViewState["Model"];
            if (modelData == null)
            {
                this.ViewState["Model"] = modelData = this.model;
            }
            return modelData;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ViewState["Model"] = value;
        }
    }
```

And CircularGaugeProperties have several collection in it

Comment: no code..no fun..how to help?

Comment: You can use a hidden field to hold the state changed/added on client, you need to make that hidden field runat="server" to access it on server